# Print all ongoing targets in Makefile

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I have written a makefile which has pretty complicated dependency, and executes with multiple jobs in parallel (make -j100 for example). I am trying to find a way to print all the current running target names. Any idea? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're looking for.  You mean within some recipe you want to be able to access the names of targets being built?  Or, from some external tool you want to find out?  Or...?

Comment: Also, "print all the current running target names" *when?* In a running loop? When the user presses a certain key? Whenever the list changes?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: `pstree -a 3418` where 3418 is the PID of your _make_. `pstree -p` is one way of finding that.

Answer (score 1):

If what you want is a kind of command that you can run from time to time while make is running, and that shows all currently executing recipes, you could slightly modify your recipes such that they first create a temporary file with the name of the target, do whatever they are supposed to do and delete the temporary file. Listing these temporary files anytime will then show you the currently executing recipes.

Example if all targets are located under the directory from which make is called (or sub-directories of it):

```
TAGSDIR := .tags
MKTAG   = mkdir -p "$(TAGSDIR)/$(@D)" && touch "$(TAGSDIR)/$@"
RMTAG   = rm -f "$(TAGSDIR)/$@"

<target>: <prerequisites>
  @$(MKTAG)
  <regular recipe>
  @$(RMTAG)
```

And list all files under `.tags` to get the names of all currently running recipes. Example with `find`:

```
find .tags -type f -printf '%P\n'
```

You could even encapsulate this in an infinite loop and refresh the list e.g. every second:

```
while true; do clear; find -type f -printf '%P\n'; sleep 1; done
```

### EDIT

[Andreas](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6121044/andreas) noticed that this works only if the targets are all located under the directory from which make is called. If a target is `../foobar`, for instance, the temporary tag file would be `.tags/../foobar`, which is not what we want.

[Andreas](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6121044/andreas) suggests to substitute `..` with `\.\.` and `/` with `\/`. We could maybe find a way to do something like this under GNU/Linux and macOS (but not exactly, you cannot have a slash in a file name) but there could still be other issues under Windows (`C:`, backslashes...).

We could also store the name of the target in a text file and use `mktemp` or an equivalent to generate the text file with a unique name. But we would then need a way to propagate this unique name from `MKTAG` to `RMTAG`. This is doable with a shell variable and a one-line recipe (or the `.ONESHELL` special target) but not very nice.

As you use GNU make we could also use `abspath` and create temporary files named `$(TAGSDIR)/$(abspath $@)` but I do not know what `abspath` does under Windows with drive letters, nor do I know if you can name a file `something\c:\something` under Windows...

So, if your targets are not all located under the directory from which make is called, the best is to use another solution.

Comment: Really nice! Though won't work should `@D` navigate through parent directory. In that case perhaps `$@` can substitute `..` with `\.\.` and `/` with `\/`?

Comment: Oh, yes, you're right, very good point (that I completely missed). If the target is located in a parent directory this will not work as expected. The substitutions you suggest would probably work, except maybe under Windows where we should also probably handle drive specifiers (`C:`), backslashes... Another option would be to store the target name in a text file and use `mktemp` or equivalent to generate the text file names. I'll edit my answer to mention the issue and suggest other solutions.